# Фон изображения при загрузке чернеет

Tags: php, gd

Добрый день. Помогите найти ошибку.

Имеется PHP код

```
function ResizeImage($image_from, $image_to, $pixels = 1, $scale = 1, $quality = 90) {
if($pixels == 0) $pixels = 100;
$h = $os = $originalsize = getimagesize ( $image_from );

if ($originalsize [0] > $pixels or $originalsize [1] > $pixels) {
    switch ($scale) {
        // по высоте
        case 1 :
            $fitheight = $pixels;
            $fitwidth = $h [0] * $fitheight / $h [1];
            break;
        // по ширине
        case 2 :
            $fitwidth = $pixels;
            $fitheight = $h [1] * $fitwidth / $h [0];
            break;
        // по наибольшей стороне
        case 3 :
            if (($h [0]) > ($h [1])) {
                $fitwidth = $pixels;
                $fitheight = $h [1] * $fitwidth / $h [0];

            } else {
                $fitheight = $pixels;
                $fitwidth = $h [0] * $fitheight / $h [1];

            }
            break;
    }
    if ($os [2] == 2 or ($os [2] >= 9 AND $os [2] <= 12))
        $i = ImageCreateFromJPEG ( $image_from );
    if ($os [2] == 3)
        $i = ImageCreateFromPng ( $image_from );
    if ($os [2] == 1)
        $i = ImageCreateFromGif ( $image_from );

    $o = ImageCreateTrueColor ( $fitwidth, $fitheight );
    if ($os [2] == 3) {
        imagealphablending( $o, false);
        imagesavealpha( $o, true);
    }
    imagefilledrectangle($o, 0, 0, $fitwidth, $fitheight, imagecolorallocate($o, 255, 255, 255));
    imagecopyresampled ( $o, $i, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fitwidth, $fitheight, $h [0], $h [1] );
    imagejpeg ( $o, $image_to, $quality );
    chmod ( $image_to, 0777 );

    imagedestroy ( $o );
    imagedestroy ( $i );
    return 2;
}
if ($originalsize [0] <= $pixels AND $originalsize [1] <= $pixels) {
    if ($os [2] == 2 or ($os [2] >= 9 AND $os [2] <= 12))
        $i = ImageCreateFromJPEG ( $image_from );
    if ($os [2] == 3)
        $i = ImageCreateFromPng ( $image_from );
    if ($os [2] == 1)
        $i = ImageCreateFromGif ( $image_from );

    if ($os [2] == 3) {
        imagealphablending( $i, false);
        imagesavealpha( $i, true);
    }
    imagejpeg ( $i, $image_to, $quality );
    chmod ( $image_to, 0777 );
    return 1;
}
```

}

При загрузке изображения PNG фон чернеет.

```
        imagealphablending( $i, false);
        imagesavealpha( $i, true);
```

Что не так в коде? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Использовал в свое время такую последовательность, чтобы избавится от фона:

```
// создаем новое изображение 
$o = imagecreatetruecolor($fitwidth, $fitheight);
// заливаем его белым цветом с альфа-каналом
imagefill($o, 0, 0, 0x7FFFFFFF);
// определяем этот цвет прозрачным
imagecolortransparent($o, 0x7FFFFFFF);
// для gif создаем палитру
if ($os[2] == 1) 
{
    $palette = imagecolorstotal($i);
    imagetruecolortopalette($o, true, $palette);
}
// копируем изображение с изменением размеров
imagecopyresampled($o, $i, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fitwidth, $fitheight, $h[0], $h[1]);
// включаем флаг сохранения альфа-канала
imagesavealpha($o, true);
// записываем результат
imagejpeg($o, $image_to, $quality);
```

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Фон всё равно стал мутным.

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский, вот пример: оригинальный png http://jpegshare.net/images/61/a0/61a029d219cd39f0377d25662b831c27.png и уменьшенная с помощью такого подхода копия: http://jpegshare.net/images/0e/00/0e00484675d237b20f271b3559996b93.png

Comment: @ПавелЖуковский, да, забыл написать, что у меня сохранение идет в том же формате, что и входной файл, а у вас все пишется в jpeg.